# Android animating a button using PNGs and OOM

Tags: java, android, animation, out-of-memory

So I've tried going about animating a button through the example given in this example: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)
and have made a huge (95 pictures) anim-list with Pngs. When trying to run the app and pressing the button, I promptly receive an error about memory not being sufficient. The file sizes are about 170k (12mb in total) . Is this too much for an animation? I realize the serious lack of regard for eventual users' storage space with this approach, but it's mostly for my own use anyway and won't matter.

The images are pretty big and need to be downscaled by the graphics engine however, and this might have to do with it?

Or is 95 pictures too much ? I can make the pictures smaller, right now they're at a whopping 4K resolution, which in hindsight is pretty dumb.

However, I can compress the pictures and make them smaller from the beginning anyway so that's not a problem. I just need to know how to fix this issue, if there's a treshold for how much can be loaded into RAM at a specific time so i can match the image sizes or if there's a way to override the default RAM settings or overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look at the file size. Image has to be uncompressed so Android can use it. The image size is more or less equal to width*height*4. 4K image takes ~35MB of memory.

Modern devices can allocate 64MB of memory per app. It means that you can load only one such image. Maybe more if your phone has higher heap limit.

AnimationDrawable is for small animations (like 100x100px). If you wish to play such a large animation, you should encode it to mp4. If you can make the images smaller or make the animation procedural - go for it.

To override the memory limit use 'largeHeap' flag or change the setting in the ROM configuration (you have to flash your device with a custom ROM).

Comment: Thanks for the good info! Can I make an mp4 and still use it as a button? I.e. would that work in the same way I think it will? If i press the button, it can play indefinitely or until the button is pressed again? 

Making it into an mp4 is easy with Vegas so that would be a nice solution I guess. How does a 170kB file get inflated to 35mb? I dont fully understand how the processor/gpu converts an image to fit to an area / AnimationDrawable..

Comment: Any idea on the above questions, Zielony? Regards

Comment: Yeah, sure. I was almost sure I have already answered that questions :D There's a dedicated component for playing videos - it's called VideoView. I'm not sure about making VideoView buttons, but it should be possible. And the 2nd question - Images are decompressed so each pixel of image is represented as one integer holding color value. It means that each pixel takes 4 bytes and image takes width*height*4bytes. In case of 4K image (4096 x 2160px) it's around 35MB